# LAMP - Use method protect /administrator joomla then can't access admin site in LEMP

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, joomla

I use [this method](http://4valves.vn) to protect my website admin.

- Step 1. Create a new directory in your root directory (eg. "newadminurl")
- Step 2. Create an index.php file in your "newadminurl " directory..

  ```
  $admin_cookie_code="3429020892";
  setcookie("JoomlaAdminSession",$admin_cookie_code,0,"/");
  header("Location: /administrator/index.php");
  ```
- Step 3. Add this to .htaccess of your real Joomla administrator directory

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !JoomlaAdminSession=3429020892
  RewriteRule .* - [L,F]

*Explanation: Now, you need to open "http://yoursite.com/newadminurl/" before you open your “administrator” path. Here we have created a cookie that expires at the end of the session and redirect to actual administration page. Your actual “administrator”path is inaccessible until you open your secret link .***

After that I changed the webserver from LAMP to LEMP . Now, I can't access my admin-site.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the code that you have added in both files and then clear your browser cache (note that Firefox caches redirects for a short while, so try from another browser).

You can always use this method - http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-password-protect-the-backend-of-a-joomla-website-with-htpasswd-and-htaccess - for protecting your backend with an additional set of credentials. We use it for our clients and it does work very well.

Comment: Thank you , itoctopus !
i removed all of code related , 
but now i'm using LEMP webserver , it didn't have .htaccess  .
LEMP uses another way to rewrite_url